# GetRawInputData sniffing character problem on different language setting

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard-events, raw-input

I'm using GetRawInputData for sniffing barcode reader data.
https://github.com/mfakane/rawinput-sharp

When I read a barcode from my barcode scanner normally it gets the right characters both rawinput and pc screen. Below image shows right scenario.

[image: USA Language Setting Mode]

My problem is, if I change the language settings of the barcode scanner to Turkey, rawinput gets additional characters like below image.

[image: Turkey Language Setting Mode]

If somebody used RawInput library before, please help me about why this is happening and I need an idea about how to sniff the data exactly like pc gets like the images.

Answer (score 0):

> I change the language settings of the barcode scanner to Turkey

I don't quite understand what do you mean by this. Also I don't know which exactly HID device type your barcode scanner is implementing.

If we talk about `RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD` data (HID Usage Page 0x01, Usage Id 0x06) - Raw Input Windows API doesn't provide any characters by itself.

`WM_INPUT` gives you PS/2 scancode of the key (in `RAWKEYBOARD.MakeCode`, it is actually converted by [KBDHID.sys driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/keyboard-and-mouse-hid-client-drivers) from HID Usages [according to this table](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/translate.pdf)) and VK_* code of the key (in `RAWKEYBOARD.VKey` field).

These presses could be mapped to characters by the call to [ToUnicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-tounicode) API. It needs as input - scan code, vk code and keyboard state (which contains for example CAPSLOCK and SHIFT state). It will convert based on **active keyboard layout of callers thread**. If you need other keyboard layout then you can use [ToUnicodeEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-tounicodeex) that have **additional parameter** `HKL dwhkl`.

Proper use of `ToUnicode`/`ToUnicodeEx` is tricky because it could emit several characters on a single key press. Also there there could be dead keys...

But for simple case it could be something like this:

```cpp
wchar_t VkToChar(uint16_t vk, bool isShift = false)
{
    uint16_t sc = MapVirtualKeyW(vk, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
    const uint32_t flags = 1 << 2; // Do not change keyboard state of this thread

    static uint8_t state[256] = { 0 };
    state[VK_SHIFT] = isShift << 7; // Modifiers set the high-order bit when pressed

    wchar_t unicodeChar;
    if (ToUnicode(vk, sc, state, &unicodeChar, 1, flags) != 1)
        return L'\0';

    if (!std::iswprint(unicodeChar))
        return L'\0';

    return unicodeChar;
}
```